# We are getting rid of our Beta status!

Tags: discussion

Upcoming Thursday the 16th of December we will lose our Beta label, and Arts & Crafts will enter its 'mature' stage! So ..

[image: Congratulations, everyone!]

This means, among other things, that we will join the list of 'Launched' website on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/1/arts?tab=beta), **the Site Stats on the main page will disappear** from the right sidebar, we'll get **a custom look** down the road, and we'll get **new moderator elections**, likely early next year.

---

The announcement on Meta can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-58-sites-that-just-left-beta).
Taken from that post in response to a comment, the following are the new requirements which were also used to determine our status change:

> For the sites that are leaving Beta today, the following criteria were determined:
>
> - The site needed to be in public Beta for at least six months
> - The site needed to have at least 1000 open questions
> - At least 70% of the questions on the site needed to have at least one upvoted answer

---

<sup>Image borrowed from [this thread on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) with the same intent.</sup>

Comment: Congrats! But I vaguely remember I read an active site needs around 10 questions daily? No?

Comment: @Vikas You're right, but they want to get rid of some of the Beta statuses of the websites that run perfectly fine but are simply too small to meet those guidelines. I think they're overall opting for a less rigid way of looking at site-status, or getting rid of the graduation process entirely, but I'd have to read through more on Meta.SE to be sure.

Comment: @Vikas That is the old standard that we haven't used for a long time.

Comment: Just checked Hinduism SE is also graduated! They also don't have 10 questions. You are right.

Comment: @Vikas Check the link I added in this post: it mentions the rules that were used and will likely be used. (Now added to the post.)